# Spring Boot + Mustache: render html only when user is authenticated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, mustache

It seems like a simple task but I did not yet find a straight answer how to do it. I'm using Mustache in a small Spring Boot application. In my header partial I'd like to render logout link only when user is authenticated. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapped object on your view for your logged user like "userObject" you can do it like this:

```
{{^userObject}}<a href='/login'>Login</a>{{/userObject}}{{#userObject}}<a href='/logout'>logout</a>{{/userObject}}
```